# SQL error: [2620 : HY000] The format or data contains a bad character

Tags: sql, casting, teradata

#### Context

The column `game_progress` is of type `varchar`. It contains values like:

> LEVEL 1, LEVEL 10, LEVEL 12, LEVEL 20

I want the WHERE condition to look at only the number in this string value.

#### What I tried

I am trying to execute following SQL query on **Teradata DBMS**.

```
SELECT user_id, CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(game_progress, 'LEVEL ', '') as INTEGER)
FROM database1.vw_ft_rockroll a
INNER JOIN database1.vw_dim_rockroll b on a.progress_id = b.progress_id
WHERE user_key = 21111111 and game_type = 'LEVEL'
and CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(game_progress, 'LEVEL ', '') as INTEGER) < 15
```

The query works if I don't include the last *where condition* ending `< 15`.
When I input `and CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(game_progression, 'LEVEL ', '') as INTEGER) < 15`, it gives me this SQL error:

> [2620 : HY000] The format or data contains a bad character

#### Another attempt fails

Also if I only try to average the level numbers it works before I add `and CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(game_progress, 'LEVEL ', '') as INTEGER) < 15`.
Once I add this, I get the following error:

> Numeric overflow occurred during computation.

```
SELECT AVG(CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(game_progress, 'LEVEL ', '') as INTEGER)) FROM database1.vw_ft_rockroll a
INNER JOIN database1.vw_dim_rockroll b on a.progress_id  = b.progress_id 
WHERE user_key = 21111111 and game_progression_type = 'LEVEL'
and CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(game_progress, 'LEVEL ', '') as INTEGER) < 15
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Please always post your database-management system (DB or DBMS) as tag to the question. Did you research on SO for `sql error 2620`? I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483651/how-do-i-filter-out-nan-float-values-in-teradata-sql) indicating [tag:Terradata] as DBMS.

Comment: Yes, sorry this is for Teradata!

Comment: Did you actually read the answers/comments of your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/66352258/2527905

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following **analytic steps** towards a solution:

1. Search the error in your DBMS Documentation (Teradata)
2. Check the values before casting
3. Pay attention to possible edge-cases

#### Search the error in your DBMS Documentation (Teradata)

Your error message:

> [2620 : HY000] The format or data contains a bad character.

It can be found explained on [Teradata Documentation](https://docs.teradata.com/r/GVKfXcemJFkTJh_89R34UQ/rvTSOgMQroEr3YaGIZUJQQ):

> This error indicates that the user has submitted a numeric-to-character conversion with an illegal format, or that, in a character-to-numeric conversion, the data or the format contains a bad character.

The recommended **remmedy** is:

> Verify the format used. If it is legal, then an illegal character is present in the data being converted from character to numeric.

### Check the values before casting

The error explanation indicates a problem during *casting* from text to number. To isolate this problem, try what happens without (before) *casting*: In your SELECT list remove the `CAST` and just leave the inner expression like:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(game_progress, 'LEVEL ', '')
```

This should return the expected values, that have the required format (without bad characters) to allow casting to a number (i.e. INTEGER).

To make `CAST(<expression> as INTEGER)` working, it is required that `<expression>` always returns a valid number, exactly an INTEGER represented as text.

But what do you actually get as result?
We assume (as given by your field description) following values:

- `LEVEL 1` replaced by REGEXP to `1`
- `LEVEL 10` replaced by REGEXP to `0`
- `LEVEL 12` replaced by REGEXP to `12`
- `LEVEL 20` replaced by REGEXP to `20`

#### Pay attention to possible edge-cases

What about `NULL` values or *empty text* ? What about malformed text not conforming the `LEVEL n` format?